# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException thrown after I updated my project from standard2.0 to .net6.0

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

As said in title I have updated my project with "dotnet tool install -g upgrade-assistant". Now when I try to run the code i get an [exception](
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnOoA.png)

Here is also my App.config that is not being initialized:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>  
    <appSettings>
        <add key="PathEmployeeDefaults" value="./EmployeeDefaults.json" />
        <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    </appSettings>  
    <system.web>
        <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
            <providers>
                <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
    </system.web>   
</configuration>
```

I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Do I need to change or update something else too?

I've also seen some other formats of .config Files. Is there a new structure of how it is supost to look like?

The other structure contains "configSections". Do I need to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clean the old project folder in **%AppData%\Local\ProjectName**

You can find caches here:
**%AppData%Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\VERSION**

If the problem persists, try to add **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** from nuget package manager.

My working .net framework 4.7.2 to migrated .net 6 project app.config template working:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test" value="https://blabla.com.tr" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

```
private static string _Test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"].ToString();
```

I got same issue before. That solved in this way.